# Loading body does not encompass parent element during lazy load

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I am implementing a table component that should be able to accept any table that has frozen rows, columns, headers, or none at all. I also want the component to load data using lazy load on scroll. When the data is being loaded on scroll a loading body element is used to cover up the loading of the data. The problem is that the loading body does not encompass the entirety of the data being loaded when there is a horizontal scroll bar. It only takes up as much space as the viewport, so when you scroll over horizontally then vertically you can see the data behind the loading body and it looks atrocious.

I've tried using css to set the loading body width to 100% and 100vw, but those don't work if you have a varying number of frozen columns. They could end up being too long or too short depending on the columns.

Here's the css I tried using for the loading body.

`.ui-table-loading-virtual-table {
  width: 100% !important;
}`

Here's the HTML I used to make the table

```
`
<div *ngIf="!isLoading; else loadingBlock">
  <div class = "p-grid">
<div class = "p-col-12">
  <p-table class="p-table" 
           [columns]="columns" 
           [value]="virtualRow" 
           [scrollable]="true" 
           [scrollHeight]= "maxHeight"
           frozenWidth={{frozenColWidth}}  
           (contextmenu)="getContextMenu($event, cm)"
           [frozenColumns]= "frozenCols" 
           [frozenValue]="frozenRows" 
           [rows]= "this.rows"
           selectionMode="single"
           (onContextMenuSelect)='getContextMenu($event.node, cm)'
           [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
           [virtualScroll]="true"
           [virtualRowHeight]="35.67"
           [lazy]="true"
           (onLazyLoad)="getData($event)"
           [showLoader] = "false">
      <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup"
                   let-columns
                   class="column-group">
        <colgroup>
         <col *ngFor="let col of columns"
              [style.width]="colWidth"
              class="col">
         </colgroup>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header"
                   let-columns >
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" >
            {{ col.header }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="frozenrows"
                   let-rowData 
                   let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pContextMenuRow]="rowData"
            (dblclick) = "executeDefaultAction()"
            (click) = "updateSelectedRow(rowData)"
            (contextmenu) = 'updateSelectedRow(rowData)'
            (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter(rowData)" 
            (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave(rowData)"
            [class.row-hover]="rowData.hover">
          <td *ngFor= "let col of columns">
            {{ rowData[col.field] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template pTemplate="body" 
                   let-rowData
                   let-columns="columns"
                    >
        <tr style="height:35.67px"
            [pContextMenuRow]="rowData"
            (dblclick) = "executeDefaultAction()"
            (click) = "updateSelectedRow(rowData)"
            (contextmenu) = 'updateSelectedRow(rowData)'
            (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter(rowData)" 
            (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave(rowData)"
            [class.row-hover]="rowData.hover"
            >
          <td *ngFor= "let col of columns"
              >
            {{ rowData[col.field] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="loadingbody"
                   let-columns="columns">
        <tr style="height:35.67px">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <div class="loading-text"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

Here's the typescript functions used to load the data.

```
blic loadChunk( length: number ) {
this.tableService.getData(this.tableUrl).subscribe((rows: Row[]) => {
  // applies rows from table service to component arrays (frozen and otherwise)
  const filteredRows = [];
  const frozenRows = [];
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    if (row.frozen) { frozenRows.push(row); } else { filteredRows.push(row); }
  });
  this.virtualRow = filteredRows.slice(0, this.virtualRow.length + length);
  this.frozenRows = frozenRows;
  const chunk = this.virtualRow.length;

  return chunk;
}, (err) => {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Service Message', detail: err.statusText });
});
```

}

```
public getInitialData() {
this.messageService.clear();
this.isLoading = true;
this.tableService.getInitialData(this.initialTableUrl).subscribe((columns: Column[]) => {
  // applies columns from table service to component arrays
  const filteredCols = [];
  const frozenCols = [];
  columns.forEach((col) => {
    if (col.frozen) { frozenCols.push(col); } else { filteredCols.push(col); }
  });
  this.columns = filteredCols;
  this.frozenCols = frozenCols;
  // this.numberCols = +this.maxWidth.substring(0, this.maxWidth.length - 2) - ((+this.colWidth.substring(0,
  this.frozenCols.length;
  const widthString = widthTobe.toString();
  this.frozenColWidth =  widthString + this.colWidth.substr(this.colWidth.length - 2, this.colWidth.length);
  this.isLoading = false;
}, (err) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Service Message', detail: err.statusText });
});
```

}

I expect the loading body to take up all of the data being loaded, but it only covers what the table shows initially before any horizontal scrolling as taken place.

Comment: can you add a minimal reproduction code ?

Comment: I added the typescript that is used for the lazy load, It gets the data just fine though. and none of the logic for the loading body takes place in the typescript besides turning it off and on.

Comment: https://imgur.com/CkdBjzj Here's a pic of what the table looks like now